# Sharepoint Designer - Workflow - adding date field to email body

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I have a list where I am creating a workflow which sends a copy of the list item to both the administrator of the list and the creator of the item. I am able to add all fields apart from the date field. Any suggestions on how to correct this or why this happens?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you doing copy paste the email content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution - My field 'Proposed Date & Start Time' contains an ampersand seemed like the character was the issue. Once removed I did not receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

Am able to do it without any hassle. I just created a date field in a list
as below

- Column name: Date
- Type: Date and Time
- Date and Time Format: Date Only
- Display Format: Standard
- Default value: None

and am able to get the value in the email using the token,
[%Current Item:Date%]

I suggest you to draft the mail using the 'Add or Change Lookup' button for each field seperately insted of typing manually.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a copy paste. Do not Copy Paste. Remove the one you have pasted and add the Proposed Date field after clicking on Add or Change Lookup. It will work. there is no limitation on SharePoint Designer Email body for a Date field.

Comment: There has been no copy and paste going on - just adding the string through the Lookup. Thanks for the response